# How to unlock colors 14 and 15?

Tags: street-fighter-v

I can see colors 11-12-13 in the shop for everyone, but I have seen online that there are supposed to be 5 new colors in the shop for each character.

Are they just coming with the zenny shop along with premium costumes later on or is there some other requirement to unlock them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have been looking around and apparently it is related to the character's level.

From what I understand, colors 11 is available to everyone immediately. (10k FM)
You unlock 12 at level 5 (2k FM) 
13 at level 10 (5k FM) 
14 at level 25 (10k FM) 
and 15 at level 50 (20k FM)